# Find time of highest sale for each date

Tags: sql, database

I have a list of sales by the minute, and I want to find the time that the highest sale occurred for each day.

Table:

```
DATE   TIME    SALE
1-1    01:10   10.21
1-1    01:29   11.32
1-2    04:34   12:32
1-2    02:32   13:21
1-3    11:32   12:12
1-3    02:53   18:32
```

I want to be able to pull the highest value for each date with the time it occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by date order by sale desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that if you have ties and want all the values, use `rank()` instead.

Comment: If i wanted to get the low, how would I do that?

Comment: @wickedflow . . . `order by sale asc`.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy and safe way to do above is:

```
Select date, time, sale from 
(Select date, time, sale, dense_rank() over (partition by date order sale desc) rn from table)
where rn = 1;
```